# React-Data-Table-component-Extenstion Library Print Export issue

Tags: reactjs, react-data-table-component

There is a problem in this library where if i used columns like this , the print and export button won't work and i get this error :

> Uncaught Error: selector must be a . delimted string eg (my.property)

```
const columns = [
  {
    name: "No.",
    cell: (a, i) => i + 1,
  },
  {
    name: "username",
    selector: row => row.username,
    sortable: true
  }]
```

but when i use it like this it works but i get alot of errors in the console :

> react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Warning: username is a string based column selector which has been deprecated as of v7 and will be removed in v8. Instead, use a selector function e.g. row => row[field]...

```
 const columns = [
  {
    name: "No.",
    cell: (a, i) => i + 1,
  },
  {
    name: "username",
    selector: 'username',
    sortable: true
  }]
```

also another issue that the column **No**. display as NaN when i try to print or export , anyone fixed this issue before ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the react errors you have shown, I believe you should use a selector for both and do something like this below.  I also understand that the 'cell' aspect is for more complex display logic involving for instance another React component displaying inside the cell.

In short, I think you can do with just using 'selector'

Cheers!

```js
const columns = [
  {
    name: "No.",
    selector: (row,i) => i + 1
  },
  {
    name: "username",
    sortable: true,
    selector: (row, i) => row.username
  }
];
```